# addNode of a managed WAS node fails on Deployment Manager

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-portal, wcs, libwcs

On an Linux machine (Machine_A), we currently have a Deployment Manager (commerce profile, DMGR profile).
On another Machine - Machine_B (commerce profile) we are creating a managed WAS node.
We need to add this node in our Deployment's Manager Cell on Machine_A. I have federated node for commerce profile in machine_A but when I am federating node with commerce profile in Machine_B then error occurred.

Error:- 
ADMU0010E: Error obtaining repository client com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: ADMU0038E: The Deployment Manager's IP address resolves as 127.0.0.1, but the Deployment Manager is not on the local machine.  The Deployment Manager's host name configuration or DNS is configured incorrectly.

Comment: How are you invoking addNode? If going by the command line, can you specify the IP address of the DMGR instead of the hostname?

Comment: (Machine_A's ip- 1.3.4.3 localhosta and Machine_B's ip 1.3.4.4 localhostb) 
I am invoking addNode from command line, I have modified hostname coresponding with IP in  hosts file in both machine Like- Machine_A hosts file 

1.3.4.3 localhosta
1.3.4.4 localhostB
 Machine_B hosts file
1.3.4.4 localhostb
1.3.4.3 localhosta

Machine_A has DMGR profile and Machine_B has Commerece profile when I am running command
 /<app_server_path>/profiles/<profile_name>/bin/./addNode.sh localhosta 8879 -includeapps
 this command run on Machine_B(1.3.4.4 localhosta)

Comment: can you generate a ping from that?  also if you look in the serverindex.xml for the dmgr what does it have as its entries in the hostname?

Answer (score 0):

You have problems in your hostname configurations. Check the /etc/hosts files on both machines and make sure there are hostnames (not localhost) entries in both mapped to the correct IP addresses. If you created DMGR profile using localhost, thats incorrect, and I'd suggest to recreate profiles or you will have to run scripts that changes the host names in profiles.